# C# Sorting Based on Rating [Updated to Clarify]

Tags: c#

I'm doing some machine learning stuff and I want to take some random samples and determine if a human agrees with the computer.  To do this a user just votes up or down on a given item.  Then I want to be able to sort by the items with the highest rating.  I want to use something more complicated than simply up-down to get good results.

I've looked into the [Wilson Interval Score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) and it seems like a decent solution, but I'm wondering if there are other alternatives.

I'm going to be using C# 4.0 if that matters.

Edit: Added below example;

Lets suppose I have 3 items and multiple people have voted on them according to the table:

```
Item    Up    Down
1       6       1
2       60      11
3       100     40
```

In this example I would like Item 3 to be listed first, item 2 second and 3 third.  This is a rough approximation of my expectations.

Item 3 has the most responses and highest relative approval.  Item 2 has more responses than Item 1 despite having a lower percentage approval.

I'm trying to list the items in terms of some sort of relative metric and algrotithm without using something like percent approval or net score; something more complicated.

Comment: Is this homework? It's ok if it is, just add a homework tag.

Comment: No its not homework.  I'm a teacher (sort of) and I'm trying to determine a way to link work to each student where each other student votes on it.  Its difficult to grade because the stuff that each student does is very different so I'm trying to let the student grade the work and then anonymously tie the work to the student who did the work.  I've simplified the problem in my posting to exactly what I need.

Comment: For me it's hard to understand exactly what you're asking.  I'd recommend rephrasing or adding more information and details to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can impliment the IComparable interface for you class. Impliment the CompareTo(T other) method. Create a case where this obj is less than the other obj and return -1. If they are the same, return 0. If this obj is greater than the other obj return 1.

When you sort a collection using the .Sort() method, it will use your rules.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No. I've added an example to my prompt.  Thanks for the response though.